# List of publications on overleaf

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I run the following on overleaf.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{}
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{}
\newcommand*{\bibyear}{}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\iffieldequals{year}{\bibyear}
        {}
        {\printfield{year}%
         \savefield{year}{\bibyear}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters based on moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\nocite{companion,bertram,cicero,augustine}
\printbibliography[title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

And get this output..
[image: This output]

But I see no detailed .bib file in the code. Can anyone tell how this is happening? I need the same setup to write my list of publications. How can I change the .bib file on overleaf to do this? Can anyone give an example of a compatible .bib file for this code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do the directives `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`, located right before `\begin{document}`,  and `\printbibliography`, located right before `\end{document}`, help?

Comment: You can indeed edit the file biblatex-example.bib on Overleaf. If you don't see a file list panel in your project, click on the "PROJECT" link in the top bar to toggle it open.

Comment: The code uses the example `.bib` file `biblatex-examples.bib` just upload or write your own `.bib` file and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code uses the example `.bib` file `biblatex-examples.bib` as indicated with `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`.

You can upload or write your own `.bib` file and add it to the project. Then you can simply use that file. Ideally your file would not be called `biblatex-examples.bib`.

A working Overleaf project with its own `.bib` is at https://www.overleaf.com/read/sffsymwrqxfy

The only code change to your example is

```
\addbibresource{cvlit.bib}
```

instead of `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` and citations of the sources contained in `cvlit.bib`